# Amadeus API Hotel description

Tags: api, amadeus

Is there a way to get a more detailed hotel description?
For example, by using this endpoint https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/reference-data/locations/hotels/by-hotels?hotelIds=ACPAR419 I'm getting such a response

```
        {
          "data": [
                   {
                    "chainCode": "AC",
                    "iataCode": "PAR",
                    "dupeId": 700140792,
                    "name": "LE NOTRE DAME",
                    "hotelId": "ACPAR419",
                    "geoCode": {
                    "latitude": 48.85306,
                    "longitude": 2.34654
                   },
                     "address": {
                     "countryCode": "FR"
                   }
                 }
                ],
        "meta": {
        "count": 1,
        "links": {
            "self": "https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/reference-data/locations/hotels/by-hotels?hotelIds=ACPAR419"
         }
       }
     }
```

What I exactly need: After getting a hotel list from the search, allow the user to open the Hotel details page of one of the found hotels and get more detailed information (Long description, images, rooms, amenities, reviews,). But the above-mentioned endpoint does not provide such a piece of information, only "Hotel name" and a few other fields. Should I combine more than one endpoint or there is already such a service and I just can't see it?

Comment: I found this useful, it is a java api that has a client: https://github.com/amadeus4dev/amadeus-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hotel Booking flow with Amadeus Self-service APIs is with 3 steps :

- Step 1: Find all available hotels in a given city or location using
  Hotel List API
- Step 2: Find the available prices with room details, descriptions and more using Hotel Search API
- Step 3: Complete the booking engine using Hotel Booking API

https://developers.amadeus.com/blog/build-hotel-booking-engine-amadeus-api

with the updated version of Hotel Search V3.0, unfortunately, the information on hotel image/address/contact details/rating/amenities is missing.

https://amadeus4dev.github.io/developer-guides/migration-guides/hotel-search/#search-hotels-by-a-city-or-geocode

Comment: Thanks! So basically after changing to the v3 there will no be any way to get that information? Or it will be added during updates.

Answer (score 0):

Just stopped using them due to less hotels in the Asian. Important that The address, contact, amenities, media values have been removed.